# How would you change this to a while loop and make it have a better run-time complexity?

Tags: algorithm

```
Algorithm foo(A,n,B,m)
    Input: arrays of integers, A of length n and B of length m
    Output: true or false
    for i := 0 to n
        for j := 0 to m
            if A[i] == B[j]
                return true
            endif
        endfor
    endfor
    return false
```

Can I change the code to be more efficient in terms of time complexity?

Comment: You need to give **much** more of a description of what you're trying to accomplish, and what you've already tried. This looks like a homework dump.

Comment: Sort the smaller array. For each element in the larger array do a binary search in the smaller sorted array.

Comment: I need help trying to write a new algorithm of foo with a while loop instead of a for loop shown above.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We're not the community which does your homework for you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Your algorithm is running in `O(n*m)` time, and is basically saying:

> Are the two lists denoted as `A` and `B` have any common items?

This can be done more efficiently if you first store one list into a set, which is implemented with more efficient data structure (Usually self balancing binary tree or hash table).

Then, you simply iterate the second list and check for matches.

Pseudo code:

```
Algorithm foo(A,n,B,m)
    Input: arrays of integers, A of length n and B of length m
    Output: true or false
    s = new Hash/Tree set
    for i := 0 to n
        s.add(A[i])
    endfor
    for j := 0 to m
        if s.contains(B[j])
           return true
        endif
    endfor
    return false
```

The new version will run in `O(logn*(n+m))` or `O(n+m)`, depending if you used tree based set or hash based set.

Comment: Note to poster: the type of loop (for versus while) is not the solution to the complexity problem, instead the data structure/algorithm is.  I agree with amit's answer.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!